# thumbnails scroller title fade position

Tags: css, positioning

In my thumbnail scroller I have a : `<span id="tt" style="display:none;"></span>` which is driven by a jquery fade in/fade out script and I want to position it outside of the thumbnails container.
the css for the span tag is : 
    `span#tt {
        position:absolute;
         left:0;
         top:0;
         }`

You can check the thumbnail scroller [here](http://outboxvision.com/test/jquery_thumbnail_scroller_horizontal_full.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, these will do the job.

```
#tt {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top:-20px; /*added*/
}
.jThumbnailScroller{
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    height:260px; /*changed 255px set it if you change #tt margin-top value*/
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden
}
.jThumbnailScroller#tS1{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:100px;
    padding-top:20px
}
```

Also edited your tip script. It was blinking If you move faster over images, because your script trying to fadein it before it finishes fadeout.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    

var link = jQuery('.jTscroller a');

link.each(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
        var imgtitle = $(this).find('img').data('title');
        $('#tt').html(imgtitle);
        $('#tt').fadeIn('slow');

        $(this).mouseleave(function()
        {
            $('#tt').hide();
        });
    });
});
});
```

Here's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dsu9a/7/

Don forget to remove these codes. This was for correcting img links with actual ones in fiddle.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var img = jQuery('.jTscroller a img');
    img.each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src','http://outboxvision.com/test/'+url)
    });
});
```

Correct your html like this.

```
<body>
    <div id="tt"></div>
<!-- rest of the code -->
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove that bottom scrollbar? and also the fade in title for every image  to have a fixed position?

Comment: Just made some improvments. What do you mean with "the fade in title for every image to have a fixed position?"?

Comment: I mean that all the images titles to fade in and out in to a specific  place.

Comment: Here is the [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i827R.jpg) to understand exactly what I'm trying to say

Comment: Create a div outside of your scroller. Set it's position to absolute and make it stay where you want it to stay. http://jsfiddle.net/dsu9a/11/

Comment: I've copied your code and it's not showing exactly as yours on jsfiddle which is very very strange.

Comment: [here](http://outboxvision.com/test/jquery_thumbnail_scroller_horizontal_full.html) is the link

Comment: You don't need position relative for anchors anymore because you said you need your title on top of the page not above the images. Check the fiddle again and I edited my answer. You should create a div outside of your scroller. And use my answers js code for creating title.

Comment: Yes, but the position of the titles should remain on the same place like in your previous [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsu9a/11/)

Comment: use #tt{position:absolute} it's not a span anymore.

Comment: I've made exactly what you say and still is not showing on the top of the screen like in your previous [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsu9a/11/). I've replace the span#tt with div id="tt". Here is the [link](http://outboxvision.com/test/jquery_thumbnail_scroller_horizontal_full.html) it's very very frustrating

Comment: Now it's working it was my mistake I've forgot to replace a $ with jQuery. Thank you anyway